# Does removal of asserts when NDEBUG is defined happen before inlining of functions?

Tags: c++, compilation, conditional-compilation

For the above example, I am trying to figure out if the increment method will actually be inlined. If the assertion will be removed by the compiler when I define the NDEBUG flag, the increment method will become a single line and thus the probability of it being actually inlined will increase.
So the question comes down to the order of removing assertions and making inline decisions by the compiler.

```
#ifndef Example_h__
#define Example_h__
#include <cassert>

class A
{
private:
    int m_value = 0;

public:
    void increment();
};

inline void A::increment()
{
    ++m_value;
    assert(m_value < 100);
}

int main()
{
  A a;
  a.increment();
}

#endif
```

Comment: [`assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) is a *macro* so it's handled by the preprocessor which is happening at [phase 4](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases#Phase_4) which is before the actual compilation (in [phase 7](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases#Phase_7)).

Comment: Yes, the preprocessor runs first, before the compiler. But even if you hadn't implemented assert using the preprocessor, constant folding almost always happens before inlining decisions are made, so this dead code would *still* get removed and the function would be inlined if appropriate. In general, trust your compiler to make inlining decisions. Code this simple is never something you need to waste much time worrying about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`assert` is a macro, so it is handled by the preprocessor before the compiler sees any of the resulting code.